# How to use advanced methods

Tags: java

So, I've been working on my method building with arguments and such, but I've come across a dillema. If I were to do this:

```
public static void setStat() {

}
```

Is it possible to create "Sub-Methods" in this case? I'll give an example:

```
public static int attack(int attack) {
    return attack;
}

public static int defense(int defense) {
    return defense;
}
```

Then tie the "Super Method" (setStat()) to the "Sub-Methods" like so:

```
setStat().attack(4);
```

If it is possible, please provide an example on how I could do this.

Comment: Not as you wrote it but you can design chaining if it's beneficial.

Comment: First of all, move out of the static world and into the instance world asap as you're losing much power by staying where you are. A decent book on OOP and Java will help you immeasurably.

Comment: `setStat` would just need to return the object that has `attack`

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to return the current `instance` i.e. `this` from your `setStat()` method and it should be changed from ,

```
public static void setStat() {

}
```

To

```
public ThisClass setStat() {
   //your logic
   return this;
}

public int attack(int attack) {
    return attack;
}
```

Then you can try to do this,

```
object.setStat().attack(4);
```

You can achieve this by moving your methods from static to instance methods and deal with current `this` object.

Comment: Great, I've got that part down. My other problem is, whenever I do:

object.setStat()/*etc.*/

I am allowed to reference the method again. How do I solve this problem?? How do I tell the method what methods it can access and which ones it cannot??